# audio, balance the sound from 2 sources

Tags: android, audio, voice, recording, waveform

I am working a phone recording software (android) which record a conversation between 2 people on a phone call. The output of each phone call is an audio file of which contains the sound from both the caller and callee.

However, most of the time, the voice from the phone that this software run on is clearer than the other. Users request me to make the 2 sound equally clear.

So the problem I have now is: I have a sound file containing voices from 2 sources with different volume, what should I do make the volume of voice from those 2 sources equally regarding the noise should not be increased. Given that this is a phone call so at a specific time there is only one person speaking.

I see at least 1 straight solution for this: making a program analyzing the wave form of the sound file, identifying parts of the sound file coming from the source having smaller voice and increase it to a level seemingly balance with the another. However this will be not an easy one to implement and I also hope that there would be better solution out there. Do you have any suggestion for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to do is to get rid of all of the noise that you do not care about.

The spectrum that you would want to use is: 300 Hz to 3500 Hz

You can cut all of the other frequencies which would substantially cut your noise. You can then apply an autoequalization gain profile or even tap into the DSP profiles available on several devices.

I would also take a look at this whitepaper if you have a chance. (IEEE or ACM membership required).

An Auto-Equalization System Based on DirectShow Technology and Its Application in Audio Broadcast System of Radio Station

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5384659&contentType=Conference+Publications&searchWithin%3Dp_Authors%3A.QT.Bai+Xinyue.QT.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have solved this problem:

1. I decode the audio into a series of Integer value thank to the storing WAV format.
The result be [xi] ;  0 < xi < 255

2. Then I have to decide 2 custom value: 
- Noise threshold? if xi > threshold => it is not noise (pretty naive!)
- How long should sound be a chunk of human voice? 
I myself choose the first value to 5 and the second value to 100ms

3. My algorithm will analyze the [xi] in to [Yi] with each Y is an array of x and each Y represent a chunk of human sound.
After that, I apply k-mean with k=2 and got 2 different cluster of Y, one belongs to the person whose voice is louder and the other belongs to the one with softer voice.

4. What left is pretty straight forward, I have to decide a parameter M, each x belong to a Y of the softer voice will multiply with M and I get the final result.